# Java .replaceAll() for $ and \

Tags: java, jasper-reports, replaceall

I have use the `replaceAll()` function in my Java ireport for one of the text field.
The following codes need to replace all the matche strings to `$` sign or `\` character . However, it is only work for `replace()` function only.

```
$P{name}.replaceAll('abc', '\$');
```

or

```
$P{name}.replaceAll('abc', '\\');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double escape character `\`

```
String str = "abc-d-abc";
str = str.replaceAll("abc", "\\$");
System.out.println(str);

String str1 = "abc-d-abc";
str1 = str1.replaceAll("abc", "\\\\");
System.out.println(str1);
```

**replace**: It will replace all occurrence of Character/String matched in String. replace can't process Regular Expression.

**replaceAll**: It will replace all occurrence of Character/String matched in String. replaceAll can process Regular Expression. **Its slower because it has to process regular expression**